# What is the python equivalent of mark directory as source in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Context: An API I am trying to use shows every example in PyCharm. But I can't get PyCharm to work on my PC. I do have Python 3.7 installed and I run it off cmd and Sublime Text.

What does PyCharm's mark directory as source do (in Windows 7)?

Is it appending a directory to the variable `%pythonpath%`? (which by the way I don't have on my computer) Or is it a custom-made importer? What can I do to simulate what mark directory as source does in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm adds Source Roots to `PYTHONPATH` in runtime. Try to mark some project directory as a source root and execute a script with the following content

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Comment: I can't run PyCharm on my computer. Would you be able to run it and share results in your answer?

Comment: As I said, the source root will be added to `PYTHONPATH` in runtime. You can mimic it with e.g. `sys.path.append` call.

Comment: My question does not ask for a method to add to `PYTHONPATH` at run time. I thought you were explaining how to see "mark source" in PyCharm is equivalent to that by "Try to mark some project directory as a source root". Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: I think he means that - how to add path to the PYTHONPATH via command line.